# Grabbing Form1's window design properties to form 2

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I'm trying to *get `Form1` Windows Design propriety objects into `Form 2`*. So basically what I want to do is use two radio buttons and put them in an if statement in form 2. Example like this

Form 1(Current code)

```
if (radioBtnOne.Checked == true)
{
  Form2 mm = new Form2();
  this.Hide();
  mm.Show();
}
```

Form 2 (What I want)

```
if (radioBtnOne.checked == true)
{
   -Action goes here-
}
```

The code in form 1 is a button method so it makes sure the radio button is checked before switching to the next form but since I checked that radio button I also want to use it in form 2 within the load method.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access anything in `form2` from `form1`, you need to pass that either by constructor of form2 or by Property. **(Constructor Injection and Property Injection)**

In Form 2, add

```
public RadioButton radioBtnOne { set; get;}
```

Then

```
if (radioBtnOne.Checked == true)
{
  Form2 mm = new Form2();
  mm.radioBtnOne = this.radioBtnOne;
  this.Hide();
  mm.Show();
}
```